# Python: Getting the Index of a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm trying to create a program that will take input of a sentence and a word and check that sentence for the word and return the index of the beginning of the word
i.e.

```
sentence = "random set of words" 
     word = "of"
     result = 9
```

This is what I tried

```
sentence = (input("Enter a sentence: "))
word = (input("Enter a Word: "))

result = sentence.split()

for x in sentence:
  if x == (word):
    boom = enumerate(word)
print(boom)
```

Comment: It should be, for x in result: so that you can get individual words each time the loop runs.

Answer (score 2):

Just use index()

a = "aa bb cc"

b = "bb"

print a.index(b)

If the OP  wants it to only count letters:

a = "aa bb cc"

b = "bb"

index_t = a.index(b)

real_index = index_t - a[:index_t].count(' ')

Comment: This will also count the whitespaces as characters, so the original example returns 11, and I think the OP wants it to only count letters, so strip the whitespaces and this is best.

Comment: Some error will happen if use strip, like string "go fire of yeah", it will be "gofireofyeah", the index of "of" will be 2 not 7.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the word only appears once, I'd do it like this:

```
sentence = sentence.split(word)
sentence[0] = sentence[0].replace(" ","")
result = len(sentence[0])
```